# Why won't the column stick to the right

Tags: html, css

I am extremely new to CSS. I have a problem, I am just playing with divs here and I have these:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>My web page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id = "first">
        <div id= "second"></div>
        <div id="third"></div>
        <div id="fourth"></div>
        <div id="fifth"></div>
        <footer></footer>
    </div>
</body>
```

and this is the CSS :

```
#first
{
    width:600px;
    height:400px;
    background-color:#666;
    margin:auto;
    position:relative;
}

#second
{
    width:100%;
    height:20%;
    background-color:yellow;
    position:relative;
}


#third
{
    margin:auto;
    width:15%;
    height:70%;
    background-color:#00FF00;
    position:relative;
    margin-left:0;
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
}

#fourth
{
    width:70%;
    height:70%;
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:auto;
    background-color:red;   
}

#fifth
{
    margin:auto;
    width:15%;
    height:70%;
    background-color:#E0AF00;
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    float:right;
}

footer
{
    background-color:black;
    height:10%;
    clear:both;
}
```

The problem is that the right column, goes beneath and doesn't stick to the right, what is the problem?

Comment: as I can see you are new to html :) also

Comment: Yes, I most certainly am.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move elements `#third` and `#fifth` to the top in the HTML markup. These two divs have `float: left|right` property, so it's most convenient to move them above the `#fourth` div.

```
<body>
    <div id="first">
        <div id="second"></div>
        <div id="third"></div>
        <div id="fifth"></div>
        <div id="fourth"></div>
        <footer></footer>
    </div>
</body>
```

I updated the code and here's the [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/67DFh/2/) to show that it works. **Notice** that I also removed all `display: inline-block` properties to remove the unwanted white-space above the `<footer>`.

Here's a visual example about this floating problem:

[image]

Comment: could you please explain why?

Comment: Because elements which are not floated are `block` elements. They intend to be _alone_ in the line. If an element with `float: right` is placed below a `block` element it can't force the `block` element to make some space for it in the same line.

Comment: See my another update. I hope it'll explain everything.